# Transactions in Tinkerpop3 DSE

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph

This is a question to understand the transaction semantics in DSE graph via TinkerPop3 Java API

As I understand, when you have `DseSession.executeGraph(String query)` is executed in a single transaction.

But what is the mechanism to achieve the same using TinkerPop3 Java API ? 
Say I want to add a vertex and then drop a few edges and then add a new vertex etc.,

I tried

```
g.V("{~label=company, id=12345}").drop().addV("company").property("id", "1").next()
```

This didn't work as I intended. (Dropping the company and adding one in a single transaction). The first vertex did indeed get deleted, however the new company was never created.

I got below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.datastax.dse.graph.internal.DseRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DseRemoteTraversal.java:60)
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that the problem is that your traversal is detached after you execute the `drop`. You may try to combine both commands via `union`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `drop()` step "kills" the traverser you are deleting, meaning nothing is returned from `drop()`. You can see that if you try this:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').drop().next()
java.util.NoSuchElementException
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

Without a traverser there is nothing to feed forward to your `addV()` step that follows. There might be a nicer way to do this, but you can work around that problem by using `inject()` to add a throwaway value as a traverser that will feed into your `addV()`. In this case, you deleted one thing, so you need to put one traverser back to trigger the single call to `addV()` thus:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').drop().
......1>   inject(1).
......2>   addV('person').property('name','stephen').next()
==>v[13]
```

I also wonder if this is a nice way to do it:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').
......1>   union(drop(),
......2>         addV('person').property('name','stephen'))
==>v[13]
```